# Gradle: Deploy JAR with custom structure: include only dir + its contents

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, groovy

**Addition to question:**

Neglected to mention (because I didn't initially think it relevant) that the `srcDir` name needs to be created within the archive as an enclosing folder for everything else.

So, the structure in the completed archive looks like this:

```
srcDirName
  aaa.class
  bbb.class
  ccc.class
  propDirName
    properties.txt
```

The following code is a solution for creating the structure, but does not answer my original question because it depends on `exclude` to keep unwanted files from `propBaseDir` from being included. I've so far been unable to find a solution using just `into` without `exclude`.

Thanks to Michael Easter for the tip on using `into`

```
def srcDir = "build/classes/java/main/examples"
def srcDirName = "examples"
def propBaseDir = "src/main/java/examples"
def propDirName = "nls"

task deployAsJar(type: Jar) {
    from {
        files(srcDir) {
            include "**/*" into srcDirName
        }
    }
    from {
        files(propBaseDir) {
            exclude "*.java"
            include "$propDirName/*"
        }
    }
    archiveFileName = "examples.jar"
    destinationDirectory = file("~")
}
```

**Original question**

I have this Gradle task which mostly does what I want:

- all files in `srcDir` are copied, but **not** `srcDir` itself
- all files in `propDir` are copied, **including** `propDir` itself

Except, all files in `propBaseDir` (enclosing dir to `propDir`) are also copied, which I don’t want.

I know I can use `exclude` to exclude files, but is there a way to copy ONLY propDir and its files into the archive?

```
task deployAsJar(type: Jar) {
    from {
        files(srcDir) {
            include "**/*"
        }
    }
    from {
        files(propBaseDir) {
            include "$propDir/**"
        }
    }
    archiveFileName = "examples.jar"
    destinationDirectory = file("~")
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working example [here](https://github.com/codetojoy/easter_eggs_for_gradle/tree/master/egg_StackOverflow_64957804).

(**Edit:** updated to reflect new information in comment/OP. Note that I'm not sure of the broader goal, so there might be a more elegant solution than using a `deployAsJar` task.)

Consider:

```
project.ext.srcDirName = 'src'
project.ext.propDirName = 'props'

project.ext.srcDir = "${projectDir}/${srcDirName}"
project.ext.propBaseDir = "${projectDir}/base"
project.ext.propDir = "${propBaseDir}/${propDirName}"

task deployAsJar(type: Jar) {
    from (srcDir) {
        include "**/*" into srcDirName
    }
    from (propDir) {
        include "**/*" into "${srcDirName}/${propDirName}"
    }

    archiveFileName = "examples.jar"
    destinationDirectory = file(".")
}
```

The trick here is to use `into` with `from` to identify the destination, inside the archive, where files should be placed.

In my example repo, this yields:

```
$ jar tf examples.jar 
src/net/codetojoy/util/Util.java
src/net/codetojoy/Employee.java
src/props/abc/abc.properties
src/props/def/def.properties
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip on using 'into'. I neglected to mention that srcDirName contains all files within the archive, including propDirName and the files it contains. I'm unable to find a solution using 'into' to create that structure.

Comment: @bigswifty I've updated the answer and the repo with the new info. Note that there might be something more elegant if you had explained the overall goal. For example, the use of `.class` files suggests that the goal involves compilation, so there might be a way to do this via configuring an existing task. (That said, I can't spend any more time on this.)

Comment: That did it. Thanks again.